# How to make git traverse soft symlinks?

Tags: symlink, git

Is there any way at all to make Git traverse a symlink and treat it as the destination file?

- I don't want to use hardlinks, they don't work across filesystems and can't be used for directories.
- I don't want to make a copy of the file, I'd have to manually keep both files in sync.
- I don't want to use bind-mounts. It requires sudo and you have to edit `fstab` to make it permanent. Doesn't work for files.
- I don't want to use patched git binaries. I want to do it with standard git.
- I don't care that it's dangerous. I'm okay with the risks.
- I have a specific use case where this makes sense. Doesn't matter what it is.
- This is an occasional thing so I'm not looking for a way to do it globally.

I understand that Git developers themselves are unsympathetic to the idea. Too bad. Guess that rules out finding some `traverse_symlinks=True` option in the manuals. I'm expecting a solution will involve some kind of arcane trickery or black magic. That is fine.

Comment: "I have a specific use case where this makes sense. Doesn't matter what it is." I disagree. I'd like to understand what you're trying to accomplish before offering any suggestions, because maybe the suggestion is to patch git (despite your desire to not do that), or use svn, or use a special file system, or do some post processing, etc etc -- all of which depend upon what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Or just keep the file in git and make the other end the link?

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), I agree with @bishop that the usecase is important here

Comment: I have to disagree with the "you shouldn't want to do this in the first place" comments here; this kind of thing is literally why symlinks exist, and _most_ UNIX tools that deal with the contents of directories have options for following symlinks (or not).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.  Git doesn't support this.

Git controls the entire state of the repository, which must live on one file system.  When it writes files into the repository or working tree, it either deletes the existing file and replaces it (for most working tree files), or writes a new file along side with `O_EXCL` and renames it into place (for most files in the `.git` directory).  As a Git contributor, I'm not aware of any case where Git will write to a file by opening it as normal, and therefore there is no opportunity to traverse the symlink.

How to accomplish your goal depends on what your actual goal is, but having Git traverse a symlink can't be that solution, since it won't work.